# cut-off rates for error correcting codes

Tags: error-correction

In pre-historic times, i.e., before 1990 or so, communications link designers used the concept of computational cut-off rates (instead of Shannon capacity) to estimate what could or could not be done in a dig-com channel. This idea goes back to Wozencraft and later promoted by Massey.

My question is: in the age of turbo codes, what, if any use and/or meaning is there for the computational cut-off rate beyond its very original meaning namely, it represents nothing more than the maximum rate that a sequential decoder can handle in finite time?

Comment: Are you soliciting opinions (off topic), or are you hoping someone has done a survey on how the term is used in contemporary literature (probably too broad)?

Comment: @Dave_Tweed this is a very specific question to which I am expecting a simple answer along the lines such as "cut-off rates are still used to explain XYZ" (where XYZ is not the maximum rate a sequential decoder can operate). As I mentioned, before turbo codes 25 years ago engineers used the cut-off rate as the actual/practical achievable capacity (well below the Shannon capacity).

Comment: Perhaps you should explain why the answer is important to you. I doubt that anyone here is going to be able to answer definitively on behalf of everyone who's ever published a paper using the term.

Comment: @hyportnex I've ever encountered the term once, in a 1980s publication, which I vaguely remember *introduced* it; so, I kind of doubt your initial statement that they were the primary method of assessing of what could be done. Remembering my Cover & Thomas information theory classic textbook, I'm pretty certain that claim is completely bogus.

Comment: @Marcus_Muller not bogus, I have used my self 30 years ago; here is the abstract from Cut-off Rate Channel Design by Narayan & Snyder  "The eloquence with which Massey advocated the use of the cut-off rate parameter for the coordinated design of modulation and coding in communication systems caused many to redirect their thinking about how communication systems should be designed. .....

Comment: ....Underlying his recommendation is the view that modulation and demodulation should be designed to realize a good discrete channel for encoding and decoding, rather than the prevailing view at the time, and still the view of many, that bit error-probability should be optimized. In this short paper, some of the research influenced by Massey's insightful suggestions on this subject is reviewed."

Comment: I'd hazard a totally uninformed guess that with the increases of computation available at the modulator and demodulator, especially FPGAs, the computational burden at the end points has ceased to be a limiting factor, compared to the SNR and bandwidth constraints of the channel, essentially unchanged in the last 30 years.

Comment: @Neil_UK in the old days there was this "folk theorem" that no man-made ie., non-random code beyond the cut-off rate could be decoded in finite time not just a tree-code using sequential decoder but any non-random code, and the supposed limit was the cut-off rate. This "folk" theorem was clearly overturned by turbo (de)coding. It was believed (not proven) by the greatest minds; looking back 25-30 years what does cut-off rate  mean *now* beyond that a sequential decoder of a convolutional code cannot operate? This has nothing to do with the actual computational cost except that it be finite.